# Responsive design jacked after deployment

Tags: css, reactjs, deployment, responsive-design, styles

Hello fellow developers!

I made this e-commerce application, made it responsive by using the built in tool in chrome. While everything looked alright in Chrome, when I deployed the application it got ultra jacked for some strange reason.

Here you can see a section of the app in Chrome and the same section on my Iphone SE.

[image]

[image]

This has happened to me before with some applications and I have no clue where I'm making a mistake. Is it using the Google Chrome built in tool, is it the media queries that I've written , is it the CSS overall. I am completely lost. I leave a little snippet to show how I normally style components and add media queries so you guys can point out any major mistakes i might be making.

```css
.products-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 2rem 0 0rem 0;
}

.products {
    width: 95%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.categories {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.category {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    padding: 0.2rem 0 0 2rem;
    font-weight: lighter;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 915px){
    .products {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .categories {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr;
        grid-auto-flow: row;
        grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
        grid-gap: 0.5rem;
        width: 78%;
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
    }
    .category {
        background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem 1rem;
        text-align: center;
        align-self: center;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 830px){
    .categories {
        width: 95%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 683px){
    .categories {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 485px){
    .category {
        font-size: 0.6rem;
        padding: 0.3rem 0.7rem 0.3rem 0.7rem;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 340px){
    .category {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 0.5rem;
    }
}
```

This is the actual component:

```js
const Products = () => {
    return (
        <div className="products-container">
            <div className="products">
                <div className="categories">
                    <h1 className="category">VIEW ALL</h1>
                    <h1 className="category">BACK IN STORE</h1>
                    <h1 className="category">BEST-SELLERS</h1>
                </div>
                <Clothes />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

*EDIT - The Sort By buttons CSS:

```css
.sortBy-btn {
    font-size: 0.6rem;
    margin: 0.5rem 0 0 2rem;
    width: 8rem;
    padding: 0.2rem;
    background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
    color: white;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
    .sortBy-btn:hover {
        background-color: grey;
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 915px){
    .sortBy-btn {
        background-color: indianred;
        color: white;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 0.8rem;
        width: auto;
        margin: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 454px){
    .sortBy-btn {
        font-size: 0.6rem;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 347px){
    .sortBy-btn {
        font-size: 0.5rem;
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you show the `sort by price` component?

Comment: Added it into the post. What I'm confused about here is that in Google Chrome it displays it exactly how I intended it to look, but on the actual device its jacked, which means that if I were to make any changes I would only be able to see what I've done by redeploying the application and hoping that all went smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error recently too. I think for safari (which is what I presume you are using when you test on iPhone) you need to apply a fixed height to the container. try adding a fixed height to the button component and see if it makes a difference

Comment: I actually downloaded chrome just because I thought its some issue with Safari, but it was exactly the same. It seems like I'm making it hard for myself by leaving the height to auto everywhere.

Comment: Yeh try adding a height and see if it fixes it for you